# Is it possible to factorise these functions each containing similar code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two Javascript functions that both use jquery-confirm (https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) and contain very similar code:

```
function cnf(cntn, fn) {
    $.confirm({
        title: "",
        content: cntn,
        confirmButton: "Yes",
        cancelButton: "No",
        confirm: function() { fn(); },
        cancel: function() { }
    });
}
function cnfprm(cntn, fn, prm) {
    $.confirm({
        title: "",
        content: cntn,
        confirmButton: "Yes",
        cancelButton: "No",
        confirm: function() { fn(prm); },
        cancel: function() { }
    });
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to factorise this code by creating another function that encapsulates the similarities of both of these calls, so the resulting code is something like:

```
function cnf(cntn, fn) {
    subfn(cntn, confirm: function() { fn(); });
}
function cnfprm(cntn, fn, prm) {
    subfn(cntn, confirm: function() { fn(prm); });
}
```

...or if there is another way to factorise the code?

Comment: If you do not pass `prm`, there will be no value there. So it will be `unefined`, essentially the same as non existent. Since the functions are identical apart from that, just use the one with `prm` and leave it empty if you want to execute the other...

Comment: Since the only difference is whether that callback passes the parameter, just treat the parameter as optional and only pass it to `fn()` when `arguments.length` is 3.

Comment: @Pointy even then, just pass the parameter regardless. It will be `undefined` anyway...

Comment: @somethinghere yes but that would potentially confuse functions that look at `arguments.length` and make decisions etc.

Comment: @Pointy true, but functions should check for values, not argument length, as that is unpredictable... I know some where that's useful, but in most functions you should not evaluate based on the length, but based on the values. Either way, I think in _most_ cases that isn;t really a problem. If it is, then yes, maybe it's better to do `if(typeof prm !== 'undefined') fn(prm) else fn()`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use this one function:

```
function cnf( cntn, fn, optionalPrm ) {
    $.confirm({
        title: "",
        content: cntn,
        confirmButton: "Yes",
        cancelButton: "No",
        confirm: function() { fn( optionalPrm ); },
        cancel: function() { }
    });
}
```

And leave `optionalPrm` empty when you do not need it. Since it will be undefined, your function is probably already going to ignore it *anyway*. Since the first two arguments are the same, it makes no difference. If the third argument is there, great, otherwise, it will be *as if* it's not there anyhow.

Comment: Ah nice, I'm a minimalist, I like this solution the best.

Comment: Wooot! Simplicity is key. (Also, for some bizarre reason, I have been saying Woot lately. Not my proudest moment.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this:

```
function cnf(cntn, fn){
  cnfprm(cntn, fn);
}

function cnfprm(cntn, fn, prm) {
  $.confirm({
    title: "",
    content: cntn,
    confirmButton: "Yes",
    cancelButton: "No",
    confirm: function() {
      if(prm !== undefined){ fn(prm); }else{ fn(); }
    },
    cancel: function() { }
  });
}
```

Comment: Why? If `prm` is _undefined_ in the parent function, it will be passed as undefined to the `fn` function. Undefined is, well, not outright _ignored_ as an argument but it will also not evluate to anything else... Just use `fn( prm )` **regardless** of whether the value exists...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the basic idea, but I'd try to avoid passing a parameter at all if the third one isn't there:

```
function cnf( cntn, fn, optionalPrm ) {
    var fnparams = [];
    for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; ++i)
      fnparams.push(arguments[i]);

    $.confirm({
        title: "",
        content: cntn,
        confirmButton: "Yes",
        cancelButton: "No",
        confirm: function() { fn.apply(undefined, fnparams ); },
        cancel: function() { }
    });
}
```

(based on code in the answer from "somethinghere")

Comment: I get the idea but it really caters to an edge case. If the function that's being called needs `arguments.length`, then by all means go ahead, but otherwise it looks like a complication that might trip you up later...

Comment: Sure; it depends on the context. If this were going into some FOS library or something like that, it might be a good idea to keep things consistent like this code does (that is, parameters not passed to the original `cnf()` won't be passed at all to the callback). In JavaScript, `undefined` has overloaded semantics and can pop up in as an explicit argument unexpectedly in a variety of ways.

Comment: That's why I made it CW however; it's basically intended as a long comment.

Comment: That explains some things :) I was wondering why it said 'community wiki'. Anyway, I see that `undefined` can cause some issues in some circumstances so indeed, this is valid information to have and a good solution to have on hand!